# Opencart Journal theme - js.cookie.js?v=3.0.7 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, cookies, opencart-3

I am using opencart version 3.0.2.0 with Journal theme 3.0.7.  Installed the plain vanilla opencart with Journal theme, cleared all the caches at browser level, template, opencart levels.

When I launch the homepage, I got the below errors.  Need someones's help here to resolve this.

```
http://mywebsite.in/catalog/view/theme/journal3/lib/cookie/js.cookie.js?v=3.0.7 404 (Not Found)
```

sdfsf

```
journal.js?v=3.0.7:741 Uncaught ReferenceError: Cookies is not defined
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (journal.js?v=3.0.7:741)
    at Function.each (jquery-2.1.1.min.js?v=3.0.7:2)
    at n.fn.init.each (jquery-2.1.1.min.js?v=3.0.7:2)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (journal.js?v=3.0.7:736)
    at j (jquery-2.1.1.min.js?v=3.0.7:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-2.1.1.min.js?v=3.0.7:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery-2.1.1.min.js?v=3.0.7:2)
    at HTMLDocument.I (jquery-2.1.1.min.js?v=3.0.7:2)
```

Got '***Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)'*** for the below javascript file.

```
<script src="catalog/view/theme/journal3/lib/cookie/js.cookie.js?v=3.0.7" ></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is my hosting provider rejecting the file name js.cookie.js.  When I changed to cookie.js it works fine.